# Sequential Timeline Animation in JavaFX 2.2

Tags: javafx-2

I am currently trying out the `Timeline` class in JavaFX 2.2. The [API-Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) states that the `Timeline`

> processes individual KeyFrame sequentially, in the order specified by KeyFrame.time

So i thought i could create a `SequentialTransition`-like animation by putting some `KeyFrame` objects in a specific order into the `TimeLine`. Each `KeyFrame` has its own `Duration`. Thats where my problems start: what is `Duration`? The offset at which the `KeyFrame` should start or the "real" duration that the `KeyFrame` takes to animate? I think the API is not very clear at that point.

Have a look at this code:

```
    Group g = new Group();
    Circle c = new Circle(15);
    c.setTranslateX(150);
    c.setTranslateY(150);
    g.getChildren().add(c);

    Timeline tl = new Timeline();
    KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(c.scaleXProperty(), 5);
    KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(c.scaleYProperty(), 5);
    KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500), kv1,kv2);

    KeyValue kv3 = new KeyValue(c.centerXProperty(), 200);
    KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), kv3);
    tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf1,kf2);

    tl.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(g,500,500));
    primaryStage.show();
```

My goal is to show the "grow"-animation of `KeyFrame` kf1 first, then the "move"-animation of kf2. The code starts the animation of every `KeyFrame` at the same time (t=0s), but with different lengths (because `Duration` is set different).

So is there any way to change this behaviour so that the `KeyFrames` are "played" in a sequential order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`KeyFrames` represent instants ("Frames") in the animation. The `time` parameter represents not a duration but the instant on the timeline when that frame occurs; you can perhaps think of it as the duration since the start of the timeline. The timeline extends from time zero to the maximum time of all its KeyValues, and it interpolates the values of the properties defined in all its KeyFrames between those Frames.

So your code creates a timeline of length 5 seconds. It interpolates the centerX to move from 0 to 200 over those 5 seconds, and the scaleX and scaleY properties to increase from 1 to 5 over the first 1.5 seconds.

To define the sequential behavior you are looking for, use a [`SequentialTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html):

```
KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(c.scaleXProperty(), 5);
KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(c.scaleYProperty(), 5);
KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500), kv1,kv2);
Timeline grow = new Timeline();
grow.getKeyFrames().add(kf1);

KeyValue kv3 = new KeyValue(c.centerXProperty(), 200);
KeyFrame kf2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5000), kv3);
Timeline move = new Timeline();
move.getKeyFrames().add(kf2);

SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition(grow, move);
sequence.play();
```

You could replace the two Timelines with a [`ScaleTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/ScaleTransition.html) and a [`TranslateTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) if you wanted.

Comment: I suppose you could also do this purely with a single `Transition`. Define `KeyFrames` at 1500 milliseconds with `scaleX=5`, `scaleY=5` and `centerX=0`, then a `KeyFrame` at 5000 milliseconds with `scaleX=5`, `scaleY=5`, and `centerX=200`. I think the `SequentialTransition` makes it clearer what is happening though.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that i could use `SequentialTransition` with `Timeline`. The part that still irritates me in your other solution is that i HAVE to use all properties in a `KeyFrame` that are used within a `Timeline` to produce a sequential animation. The moment i leave out the `centerX` property in the first `KeyFrame` the timeline starts to "play" all `KeyFrames` at the same time. Any idea why this is done that way?

Comment: It's fairly intuitive to me. I don't know much (anything) about traditional (i.e. non-computer generated) animation, but I think the terminology is based on that. Animations are comprised of a sequence of frames. In a Timeline you don't define all the frames, just certain KeyFrames and the remaining Frames are interpolated. By default any property that occurs in the Timeline is interpolated: there doesn't seem to me to be any other obvious way to do it.

Comment: Note that you can have multiple `KeyFrame`s at the same timepoint, so you could still factor the "move" and the "grow" into separate `KeyFrame`s within a single `Timeline`. The `SequentialTransition` (which is comprised of any `Animation` objects is still the way to do it, though.